# How to append a listitem in first position of list using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to append a listitem in first position of list using Jquery?

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>  
</ul>
```

is it possible to append a list item before first `<li>` with jquery. I try to `$('#mylist li:eq(1)').before("<li></li>")`. But it not works?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: `:eq()` uses a zero-based index; the first one is `:eq(0)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are selecting the second `li` element, try this:

```
$('#mylist li:eq(0)').before("<li>first</li>");
//or $('#mylist li:first')...
```

or you can use `prepend` method.

Comment: This will fail when the list is empty and have no li inside the ul, the @zackdever answer work on that case

Answer (score 51):

```
$('#mylist').prepend('<li></li>')
```

Answer (score 5):

This snippet will solve the problem. Or go to the [link](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to learn more.

```
$('#mylist').prepend('<li>New Item</li>');
//use jQuery's prepend method.
```

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $('#mylist').prepend('<li>New Item 1 added</li>')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  
  <body>
  <ul id="mylist">
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
  <li>Fourth Item</li>  
  </ul>  
  <button> click to add first li</button>
  </body>
  
</html>
```